# explain() doesn't show a queryPlanner/winningPlan in MongoDB Compass shell

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to add indexes on my collection and to check how they are used using the `.explain()` method to see the `winningPlan` and the `rejectedPlans`.

In the MongoDB documentation I saw 2 ways of doing it:

1. `db.collection.explain().find({...})`
2. `db.collection.find({...}).explain()`

To get the 2 mentioned field they recommend the following command:
`db.collection.find({...}).explain.queryPlanner`
The expected return should be in this structure:

```
   queryPlanner: {
   namespace: <string>,
   indexFilterSet: <boolean>,
   parsedQuery: {
      ...
   },
   queryHash: <hexadecimal string>,
   planCacheKey: <hexadecimal string>,
   maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: <boolean>,
   maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: <boolean>,
   maxScansToExplodeReached: <boolean>,
   winningPlan: {
     stage: <STAGE1>,
     inputStage: {
       stage: <string>,
       ...
     }
   },
   rejectedPlans: [
     <candidate plan1>,
   ]
  }

}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't return anything.

Is there any other way to see those fields?

Comment: What does `db.collection.find({...}).explain().queryPlanner` show?

Comment: Explain is a function, not an object, so you need to actually call it: `db.collection.find({...}).explain().queryPlanner`

Comment: @Joe there is still no outcome even if I put the parantesis

Comment: @rickhg12hs the output should look something like this:

`queryPlanner: {
   namespace: <string>,
   indexFilterSet: <boolean>,
   parsedQuery: {
      ...
   },
   queryHash: <hexadecimal string>,
   planCacheKey: <hexadecimal string>,
   maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: <boolean>,
   maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: <boolean>,
   maxScansToExplodeReached: <boolean>,
   winningPlan: {
     stage: <STAGE1>,
     inputStage: {
       stage: <string>,
       ...
     }
   },
   rejectedPlans: [
     <candidate plan1>,
   ]
  }
}`

Comment: I am mostly interested in the **winningPlan** and **rejectedPlans** fields

Comment: What is your collection name?

Comment: @rickhg12hs the collection is named 'statistics'

Comment: What is the output of `db.statistics.find({...}).explain().queryPlanner`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I already said that in a comment, but I added it in the question too

Comment: basically I want to use the things they mention in this page of the documentation, but nothing mentioned here works for me: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/explain-results/

Comment: Actually, I mean when you actually run it in the MongoDB Compass `mongosh`, what is the output printed when you type `db.statistics.find({...}).explain().queryPlanner` and hit enter.  `mongosh` will generate some output.  What is it?

Comment: @rickhg12hs i have no output. the console is empty after this command

Comment: Are you in the correct database? `use theDatabaseYouWant`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes. all the simple find queries work, but when I add anything related to the explain() method there is no output

Comment: Which version of Compass are you using?  What version of the MongoDB server are you connecting to?  Do you experience the same thing with the standalone `mongosh`?